# Valor cambiante de las variables globales en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un script con Javascript y encuentro algo que no entiendo.

He creado una serie de funciones. Fuera de ellas he declarado (vacias ) unas variables que entiendo globales por estar declaradas fuera y que tomarán el valor de dentro de las funciones.
Posteriormente utilizaré el valor de estas variables.

El caso es que, por medio de la consola puedo acceder al valor de estas variables pero hay veces que me devuelve el valor y otras que me devuelve undefined.

Recargo la página me vuelve a devolver undefined. Si salgo del navegador y vuelvo a lanzar el index.html me muestra el valor correctamente.

```
  function H(){
      var re = /\tH\s*((.*),\s*(.*))\(/gm; 
      if ((m = re.exec(resultados_texto)) !== null) {
        if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
            re.lastIndex++;
        }
        // View your result using the m-variable.
        // eg m[0] etc.
        Hlatitud = m[2];
        Hlongitud = m[3];
        return (m[1])
    }
}
```

Solo puedo ver el valor de Hlatitud si previamente he llamado a la funcion H()

Hasta que no llamo a la función me devuelve undefined

Comment: Seria bueno que coloques el código de tu script, para darte una mejor explicación, ya que lo que te esta pasando es algo con scope.

Comment: Precisamente porque son variables globales es que otro código que no sean tus funciones pueden estar modificando sus valores. En la medida de lo posible no uses variables globales.

Comment: El código que colocas no es suficiente para encontrar el poblema. Debido a que son variables globales algo más puede estar modificándolas. Nuevamente te recomiendo que no utilices variables globales sino que las pases como parámetro a tu función.

Comment: El código que compartes no es suficiente para entender qué está sucediendo. Falta la declaración de tus variables globales. Falta el llamado a tu función. Por lo que entiendo tienes declaradas tus variables globales y luego llamas a tu función. Si revisas el valor de tus variables antes de realizar el llamado a la función, va a ser `undefined`, pero luego de ejecutar la función tendrán valor. Al recargar la página, seguramente estés definiendo tus variables nuevamente, por lo cual vuelven a ser `undefined`.

Comment: Ya veo que es un tema de scope.
Vengó de Python y aquí esto es más complejo.

Comment: Es el valor de tu Target para tu RegEx. La declaración de dicha función está bien, pero mejor si lo validas. Quizás ahí tengas problemas de Scope, o existe pero en otras de tus funciones, como también puede ser Hoisting. aprende q Javascript eleva la declaración de variables o la declaración de funciones pero nunca sus asignaciones. Suerte.

Comment: Se me olvidó darte un apoyo. Esto te informará http://jstherightway.org/es-es/

Comment: Amigo, lo que sucede (de acuerdo al código descrito) es que tus variables no son asignadas hasta que ejecutas tu función, mientras tanto, las variables serán `undefined`.

Te recomiendo la lectura de [4.2. Ámbito de las variables - LibrosWeb.es](http://librosweb.es/libro/javascript/capitulo_4/ambito_de_las_variables.html).

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que lo de adentro de la función no se ejecuta (solo se compila para ejecutarse después).
Recién cuando se ejecute H() se ejecutan las líneas internas de la función. 
Para no ver el undefined  se puede agregar arriba de todo:

```
Hlatitud = "valor inicial";
console.log(Hlatitud);
```